# Network without Server: NAT punchthrought

Tags: unity, networking, multiplayer

How do i make 2 players connect and play together ?

Assumptions:

1) Game has no server.
2) Player only has 1 computer.
3) Player cannot configure his router or open a port.
4) Player does not want to share his PC for multiplayer.
5) Reasonable delay is allowed: up to 1 hour per packet / player action.
6) Ipv4 internet is used
7) Players can connect to any website.

Solutions I considered but cannot get them to work:
1) Posting in a random forum you don't own. Soon the thread that 10 million players use, approaches 60gb data per hour and gets closed by a moderator. Gameover.

2) Sending Data by Email.
  a) I know no email api.
  b) players will risk their email credentials.

3) Having an external server manage the initial connection.
  a) I know none that are free. 
  b) I am not paying money.

More specific :
I am using unity, i am willing to port solutions if you find a free site or solution that works.

Comment: What's wrong with play-by-email? All the players really risk to reveal is their email address, not their passwords (unless you have a really stupid vulnerability) and SMTP/POP3/IMAP are really simple protocols with wide library support.

Comment: just tested it, it requires a password to send a mail :
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/433283/how-to-send-email-with-c.html

The code in question:
smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("youraddress@gmail.com", "yourpassword") as ICredentialsByHost;

Comment: Yes, of course it requires a password, but that password is only exchanged between client and mailserver, just as usual with an email client. The password doesn't need to go to the other players.

Comment: the player willl have to trust the game, the game could be an evil virus, why should i trust it ? because it has 3d graphics ?

Comment: If your game *were* a virus, you could already steal all kinds of data the moment they install it. Running your executable already means they need to trust you.